# Dynamically change count of PagerIndicator in ViewPager or PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter, viewpagerindicator

[image]

What effect I want to have is :

1. **number of Bottom Circle indicator must be half of page count when page width is half.**
2. **number of Bottom Circle indicator must be as much as page count when page width is full.**

also, there is an another request:

1. **can i scroll two pages in single scroll when page width is half?**
2. **and scroll only one page in single scroll when page width is full?**

page width is acquired by PagerAdapter#getPageWidth()

can anyone give the perfect solution for this? without making two layout files or two adapters?

Here's the whole source code that I have developed to achieve this GIF based activity.

Question Improvement will be accepted.

https://github.com/raghavsatyadev/DemoPort

Comment: i do not understand, you meam scrolling? left right?

Comment: yes scrolling also. when width is half I want to scroll two pages at the same time (on a single swipe)

Comment: Would you please answer my question.In half Width Mode, If you scroll right or left, both items would change or no just one of them would change ? what is your desired behavior ?

Comment: I want both items changed in half view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best practice in this case is to bind the view[s] to a view group in the adapter. In your adapter you should create a linear layout and add as much children as you want

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) { 
   LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,MATCH_PART);
   param.weight = 1.0f;

   for (int i; i < getChildrenInPage() ; i++) {
      MyView myView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_layout, null)
      myView.bind(getDataForPosition(getChildrenInPage()*position + i))
      ll.add(myView, params));
   }
}
```